# Lightweight Java Object cache API

Tags: java, caching

### Question

I'm looking for a Java in-memory object caching API. Any recommendations? What solutions have you used in the past?

### Current

Right now, I'm just using a Map:

```
Map cache = new HashMap<String, Object>();
cache.put("key", value);
```

### Requirements

I need to extend the cache to include basic features like:

- Max size
- Time to live

However, I don't need more sophisticated features like:

- Access from multiple processes (caching server)
- Persistence (to disk)

### Suggestions

In-Memory caching:

- [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) CacheBuilder - active development. See this [presentation](https://github.com/liubo404/it-ebooks/blob/master/pdf/JavaCachingwithGuava.pdf).
- [LRUMap](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/map/LRUMap.html) - Config via API. No TTL. Not purpose built for caching.
- [whirlycache](http://whirlycache.dev.java.net/) - XML config. Mailing list. Last updated 2006.
- [cache4j](http://cache4j.sourceforge.net/) - XML config. Documentation in Russian. Last updated 2006.

Enterprise caching:

- [JCS](http://jakarta.apache.org/jcs) - Properties config. Extensive documentation.
- [Ehcache](http://ehcache.sourceforge.net) - XML config. Extensive documentation. By far the most popular according to Google hits.

Comment: Can you edit the Suggestions In-Memory caching section to include Guava Cache? I was looking for a lightweight caching mechanism just like you, and found this question, but didn't find Guava because it's way down. Now I use the guava cache package, and it's AMAZING.

Comment: Done. :-) Very glad you like it!

Comment: Maybe you also want to consider to add the relatively new [cache2k](http://cache2k.org). On their [benchmarks page](http://cache2k.org/benchmarks.html) it is said that it has much better performance than ehcache and Guava.

Comment: Try `@Cacheable` from [jcabi-aspects](http://aspects.jcabi.com): http://www.yegor256.com/2014/08/03/cacheable-java-annotation.html

Answer (score 58, accepted):

[EHCache](http://ehcache.sourceforge.net/) is very nice.  You can create an in memory cache. Check out their [code samples](http://ehcache.sourceforge.net/documentation/samples.html) for an example of creating an in memory cache.  You can specify a max size, and a time to live.

EHCache does offer some advanced features, but if your not interested in using them - don't.  But it's nice to know they are there if your requirements ever change.

Here is an in memory cache.  Created in code, with no configuration files.

```
CacheManager cacheManager = CacheManager.getInstance();
int oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60;
Cache memoryOnlyCache = new Cache("name", 200, false, false, oneDay, oneDay);
cacheManager.addCache(memoryOnlyCache);
```

Creates a cache that will hold 200 elements, and has a ttl of 24 hours.

Comment: Does EHCache just refer to the object or it serialize and then deserialize the object instead?

Comment: Is EHCache a heavyweight solution? We're looking into existing caching solutions to implement an API cache on Android.

Comment: It's too heavy for Android. I'm using Kitty cache and it's so perfect!

Comment: @Stevet K,I'm late to know this Cache technology ,but I guess getInstance() was removed or changed.

Answer (score 47):

I really like the [`MapMaker`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html) that comes with [Google Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) ([API](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/))

The JavaDoc has a pretty neat example that demonstrates both its ease of use and its power:

```
ConcurrentMap<Key, Graph> graphs = new MapMaker()
   .concurrencyLevel(32)
   .softKeys()
   .weakValues()
   .expiration(30, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
   .makeComputingMap(
       new Function<Key, Graph>() {
         public Graph apply(Key key) {
           return createExpensiveGraph(key);
         }
       });
```

Furthermore, release 10.0 of Guava introduced the much more extensive [`com.google.common.cache` package](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/package-summary.html) (there's a [nice wiki entry on how to use them](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained)).

Comment: [guava user guide on caches](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained)

Comment: @mxttie: thanks, I've added the link, feel free to suggest an edit for additions like this.

Answer (score 10):

You can also check out my little cache library called KittyCache at:

https://github.com/treeder/kitty-cache

There are some performance benchmarks vs ehcache.

It's used in the [SimpleJPA](http://code.google.com/p/simplejpa/) project as a second level cache.

Comment: Nice one, but if only it has TTL.

Comment: Thanks ! just the code I was typing before I thought to check if someone has already open sourced something :)

Comment: @RosdiKasim it does have TTL actually on put() call, eg: cache.put("mykey", value, 500); 500 is TTL.

Comment: @TravisR Well..., it didn't have TTL back then.. :p

Comment: Ahh, didn't realize how long ago that comment was.

Answer (score 9):

You can check out LinkedHashMap to implement a simple cache without third party jars:

```
    Map <String, Foo> cache = new LinkedHashMap<String, Foo>(MAX_ENTRIES + 1, .75F, true) {

        public boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry<String, Foo> eldest) {
            return size() > MAX_ENTRIES;
        }
    };
```

then you can get from the cache like

```
    Foo foo = cache.get(key);
    if (foo == null && !cache.containsKey(key)) {
        try {
            FooDAO fooDAO = DAOFactory.getFooDAO(conn);
            foo = fooDAO.getFooByKey(key);
            cache.put(key, foo);
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            logger.error("[getFoo] SQL Exception when accessing Foo", sqle);
        }
    }
```

rest left as exercise for reader :)

Comment: I don't think this method has TTL capacity. It would be a good start towards rolling your own, though.

Comment: Yeah, I'll leave the TTL stuff as part of the reader exercise :p - and of course the third party libs will have been tested far more than rolling your own.

Answer (score 9):

Guava's [MapMaker](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/18.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html) has been replaced by their [CacheBuilder](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html) class.

Answer (score 5):

[JCS](http://jakarta.apache.org/jcs/) is tried and true.  Even though it is light as far as caching mechanisms go, you might dig into the actual code and mimic what they do with HashMap under the covers to exactly what you need and no more.  You seem to have a pretty good idea of what you are looking for.

Comment: I assume you mean it's *not* light as far as caching mechanisms go? It seems to be one of the most popular enterprise solutions, though.

Answer (score 3):

memcached has client for Java. http://www.danga.com/memcached/ Requires separate process to be a caching server, but powerful thing.