# Looking for simple Java in-memory cache

Tags: java, caching

I'm looking for a simple Java in-memory cache that has good concurrency (so LinkedHashMap isn't good enough), and which can be serialized to disk periodically.

One feature I need, but which has proved hard to find, is a way to "peek" at an object.  By this I mean retrieve an object from the cache without causing the cache to hold on to the object any longer than it otherwise would have.

**Update:** An additional requirement I neglected to mention is that I need to be able to modify the cached objects (they contain float arrays) in-place.

Can anyone provide any recommendations?

Comment: I'm looking for something similar that is "within process" and lighter weight. I want to use it to store some data within an Eclipse plugin in the heap. Ehcache and JCS seem too heavyweight/distributed/J2EE for my taste.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lightweight Java Object cache API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230649/lightweight-java-object-cache-api)

Comment: I will recommend Apache Ignite(https://ignite.apache.org/)

Comment: That this question is closed (6 years after the fact) and it still something people are wondering today, show how SO's moderator system is failing.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Since this question was originally asked, [Google's Guava library](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained) now includes a powerful and flexible cache.  I would recommend using this.

Comment: Please note that Spring does not support Guava cache anymore: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44175085/why-did-spring-framework-deprecate-the-use-of-guava-cache

Comment: @sanity does it implement Jcache?

Comment: [Caffine](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine) is also nice and performant caching library. Caffeine is a high performance, near optimal caching library based on Java 8. Caffeine provides an in-memory cache using a Google Guava inspired API

Answer (score 39):

[Ehcache](http://ehcache.sourceforge.net/) is a pretty good solution for this and has a way to peek ([getQuiet()](http://ehcache.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sf/ehcache/Cache.html#getQuiet(java.lang.Object)) is the method) such that it doesn't update the idle timestamp.  Internally, Ehcache is implemented with a set of maps, kind of like ConcurrentHashMap, so it has similar kinds of concurrency benefits.

Comment: Thanks, an additional question: If I retrieve an object from EHcache (say, an array), and modify it - will the object be updated in the cache?  ie. is EHCache maintaining references to the objects?

Comment: I believe so but to do this safely you must appropriately lock the object, of course.

Comment: I love ehcache, however, it is a 10mb jar.  Way too big.

Answer (score 36):

If you're needing something simple, would this fit the bill?

```
Map<K, V> myCache = Collections.synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<K, V>());
```

It wont save to disk, but you said you wanted simple...

Links:

- [Collections.synchronizedMap](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap(java.util.Map))
- [WeakHashMap](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/WeakHashMap.html)

(As Adam commented, synchronising a map has a performance hit. Not saying the idea doesn't have hairs on it, but would suffice as a quick and dirty solution.)

Comment: Synchronizing an entire gigantic map is a hefty penalty. You could easily store weak types in a concurrent hash map and remove them periodically.

Comment: ConcurrentHashMap is better than Collections.synchronizedMap http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6692008/java-concurrenthashmap-is-better-than-hashmap-performance-wise

Comment: Performance-wise, ConcurrentHashMap absolutely performs better, but it doesn't share the properties of a WeakHashMap with regard to allowing the garbage collector to reclaim memory. This may or may not be important to you.

Comment: Then use `ConcurrentHashMap<WeakReference<T>>`. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html

Answer (score 21):

Another option for an in-memory java cache is [cache2k](http://cache2k.org).
 The in-memory performance is superior to EHCache and google guava, see the [cache2k benchmarks page](http://cache2k.org/benchmarks.html).

The usage pattern is similar to other caches. Here is an example:

```
Cache<String,String> cache = new Cache2kBuilder<String, String>() {}
  .expireAfterWrite(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)    // expire/refresh after 5 minutes
  .resilienceDuration(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // cope with at most 30 seconds
                                          // outage before propagating 
                                          // exceptions
  .refreshAhead(true)                       // keep fresh when expiring
  .loader(new CacheLoader<String, String>() {
    @Override
    public String load(final String key) throws Exception {
      return ....;
    }
  })
  .build();
String val = cache.peek("something");
cache.put("something", "hello");
val = cache.get("something");
```

If you have google guava as dependency then trying out guava cache, may be a good alternative.

Comment: cruftex,if I close my application the cache will destroy all registred data or no ?

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
import java.util.*;

public class SimpleCacheManager {

    private static SimpleCacheManager instance;
    private static Object monitor = new Object();
    private Map<String, Object> cache = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<String, Object>());

    private SimpleCacheManager() {
    }

    public void put(String cacheKey, Object value) {
        cache.put(cacheKey, value);
    }

    public Object get(String cacheKey) {
        return cache.get(cacheKey);
    }

    public void clear(String cacheKey) {
        cache.put(cacheKey, null);
    }

    public void clear() {
        cache.clear();
    }

    public static SimpleCacheManager getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            synchronized (monitor) {
                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = new SimpleCacheManager();
                }
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }

}
```

Comment: The problems with relying on a synchronized map were already discussed in other answers.

Comment: @sergeyB : I was looking for a similar solution which is simple for implementing cache... Thanks

Comment: `public static SimpleCacheManager getInstance() {` should be `public synchronized static SimpleCacheManager getInstance() {` otherwise `if (instance == null) {` is not thread safe. In which case you can remove the monitor object all together since synchronization takes place for all getInstance() calls, see: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073352/core-java/simply-singleton.html?page=2

Comment: May I recommend using an enum for singleton? https://dzone.com/articles/java-singletons-using-enum

Answer (score 10):

You can easily use [imcache](https://github.com/Cetsoft/imcache). A sample code is below.

```
void example(){
    Cache<Integer,Integer> cache = CacheBuilder.heapCache().
    cacheLoader(new CacheLoader<Integer, Integer>() {
        public Integer load(Integer key) {
            return null;
        }
    }).capacity(10000).build(); 
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Try [`@Cacheable`](http://aspects.jcabi.com/apidocs-0.17.2/com/jcabi/aspects/Cacheable.html) from [jcabi-aspects](http://aspects.jcabi.com/annotation-cacheable.html). With a single annotation you make the entire method result cacheable in memory:

```
public class Resource {
  @Cacheable(lifetime = 5, unit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
  public String load(URL url) {
    return url.openConnection().getContent();
  }
}
```

Also, read this article: http://www.yegor256.com/2014/08/03/cacheable-java-annotation.html

Answer (score 3):

How about this: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jcs/ (updated to new address, as JCS is now in Apache Commons)

Comment: It looks like @sanity wanted a light cache.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Ehcache](http://ehcache.sourceforge.net/)? It allows you to plug in your own caching expiry algorithms so you could control your peek functionality.

You can serialize to disk, database, across a cluster etc...