# Putting values into a Map

Tags: java, parsing, hashmap, bufferedreader

Hello I am Reading in a File and parsing it into a String and a Double.

The parsed values are then put into a ConcurrentHashMap.
(String is the Key and the Double is the Value).

```
public class Test {
    public static Map<String, Double> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Double>();

    public void readFromFile() throws IOException {

        String text = "Hello.txt";
        // Hello contains:
        // HELLO 12312
        // BYE 12213
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                new FileInputStream(text), Charset.forName("UTF-8")));

        while ((text = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            // Splits the read line in two where the space char is the
            // separating
            String[] stuff = text.split(" ");

            map.put(stuff[0], Double.parseDouble(stuff[1]));

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Test t = new Test();
    t.readFromFile();
    System.out.println(map);

    }
}
```

I have been told that this is not a good way of putting values from File into my Map.
Hello.txt has around 400.000 entries
So my two questions:

Why is it bad to use this method?

How could I improve on it?

Also if this is a perfectly fine way of using put then please say so as well.

Comment: Does your Map really need to be thread-safe ?

Comment: Good or bad way changes according to your intention of use. If you want to get value of a key in O(1) time, it's good to use map. If you want you map thread safe, then concurrent hash map (with sync overhead) is a good way. If you want to iterate and do some process in insertion order, you can use a list (linked or arraylist), etc.. So what is your intention?

Comment: Thank you for the responses. I am using the map with threads. This is just a sample code from my project to enquirer if this is an alright way of using put. So the map has to be concurrent. (I forgot to take it out here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the answer from @irreputable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6692008/java-concurrenthashmap-is-better-than-hashmap-performance-wise) the performance of ConcurrentHashMap is only slightly worse than that of HashMap.  So unless performance here is absolutely critical,or you are certain that there is no need for thread-safety, your implementation is perfectly fine.