# Scala Map and ConcurrentHashMap throw a java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java, multithreading, scala, containers, java.util.concurrent

With this simple code

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
new java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap[String,String]  ().toMap.put("abc","def")
```

Scala throw a java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException.

Why ?

Comment: What does `toMap` do? ConcurrentHashMap is already a map. I guess, `new java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap[String,String]  ().put("abc","def")` should work fine.

Answer (score 7):

Well this is what happens (I think):

1. You create a concurrent java hash map with `new java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap[String,String]()`
2. Then you convert it to an immutable scala Map with `toMap`
3. As `toMap`is not defined on `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap` an implicit conversion to a *mutable* scala map is applied. And `toMap` then makes of this *mutable* `Map` an *immutable* `Map`.
4. Then you call 'put(...)' which is not defined on `scala.collection.immutable.Map`.
5. The scala compiler however, conveniently, finds a conversion from `scala.collection.immutable.Map` to `java.util.Map` in your import `import scala.collection.JavaConversions._` which has a `put(...)` method defined. However, the conversion returns a wrapper extending `AbstractMap`.
6. But there is no `put(...)` method implemented in that wrapper. Therefore, the call ends up in the default implementation of `java.util.AbstractMap` which does not really implement `put(...)` but instead throws an `UnsupportedOperationException`

I guess the confusion caused by this, is one reason most scala developers prefer `import scala.collection.JavaConverters._` over `import scala.collection.JavaConversions._` nowadays.

So, I think, this might be what you want to do:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
new java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap[String,String]().asScala.put("abc","def")
```

Comment: Just a very slight change: the last conversion is from `scala.collection.Map` to `java.util.Map`. But it actually returns a wrapper extending `AbstractMap` which delegates methods like `get` to corresponding `scala.collection.Map` methods. And there is no method corresponding to `put`, so it isn't overridden and `AbstractMap`'s implementation is inherited.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Thanks , was a bit lazy there. I edited my answer, hope it's more accurate now.

Answer (score 4):

Unlike Java, the default collections in Scala are immutable. If you take a look at the api for `Map` (found [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/#scala.collection.immutable.Map)) you'll see that `Map` lacks a method `put`. So the exception is telling you, quite rightly, that `Map` can't do what you want it to do. If you want to fill the `Map` with values:

```
Map("abc" -> "def")
```

By the way, an immutable collection is already thread-safe. No need to use a `ConcurrentHashMap`.

Comment: Re, "By the way... no need to use a ConcurrentHashMap."  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6692008/java-concurrenthashmap-is-better-than-hashmap-performance-wise

Comment: @jameslarge their performance is pretty much equals starting from Java7, which is directly explained in the answer to the question you're pointing to. Or did you mean something else?

Comment: moreover the performance of scala's immutable map is additionally optimized: [benchmark](https://gist.github.com/rklaehn/26c277b2b5666ec4b372) and [src](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/HashMap.scala#L166). It depends on actual requirements though