# DataSet without using System

Tags: c++, dataset

I am trying to find an example of a Dataset implementation that does not use .NET in any fashion. Reason being, I want to create an application that can be used on multiple platforms not just windows.

Comment: Why do you need a full DataSet implementation if you're not using C++/CLI?

Comment: According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.aspx , System.DataSet "Represents an in-memory cache of data."  I think you can do that without .NET, yes.

Comment: Are you asking how to access a database on multiple platforms?

Comment: I am using C++ just not .NET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fear this isn't possible. The DataSet class you want to use is not available in the C++ programming language as a basic type or class. [This MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) shows that the DataSet class was introduced by Microsoft in the .NET Framework version 1.1 . Finding a C++ class that provides the same functionality outside the .NET Framework won't be easy.

I'm not familiar with this specific class, but on the page provided, the class is described as *"Represents an in-memory cache of data."* If you want to create a multiplatform application, I would consider Java. An alternative for the Microsoft DataSet class could then be found in [this Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/575685/looking-for-simple-java-in-memory-cache).