# Best data structure in Java when using HashSet as a cache

Tags: java, caching, concurrency, guava, java.util.concurrent

My use case is this:

I need to cache a set of strings for frequent read access. The cache is updated by a daemon thread periodically. Moreover, the cache element will **never** get updated individually, it would always be

```
set.clear();set.addAll(List)
```

I'm currently using a `HashSet` protected by an `ReentrantReadWriteLock`. Is there a **better** way to do this?

Comment: You could use one of the many robust Java caches that already exist. See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/575685/looking-for-simple-java-in-memory-cache).

Comment: Could you name a few? I thought about Guava's LoadingCache but it takes more memory than I need, I don't really need a map in this case.

Comment: In what way does it take more memory than you need? That's a very vague assertion. The JVM manages your memory, and I would prefer an existing solution to rolling my own. And yes, [`LoadingCache`](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained) looks fine.

Comment: LoadingCache<K, V>, which is essentially a hash map, whereas I only need to cache a set of strings. How does JVM optimize in this case? My set could have tons of entries.

Comment: Read the Javadoc. And Java (especially 64-bit Java) can address *tons* of memory.

Comment: @bohanl HashSet in the jdk is implemented with a HashMap internally...

Comment: A `Set` doesn't take any less memory than a `Map` for any of the JDK's implementations.

Answer (score 2):

One option would be a volatile set:

```
private volatile Set<String> set = new HashSet<> ();

public void update() {
  Set<String> newSet = getNewData();
  set = newSet;
}
```

This is thread safe (if you don't let other code access the set itself) and does not require locking. One drawback is that you hold both sets in memory until the next GC (not sure how much space is used per entry - to be tested).

Comment: You'd probably want to make the set unmodifiable or immutable to guard against accidental updates.