# Separating frontend from backend

Tags: caching, sass, frontend, vaadin8

For development purposes I need to have a better separation of my frontend from my backend.

We have an application built using Vaadin 8, and currently we are experiencing some problems on how our back end updates are pulled into our designer’s local environment causing most of the time compilation problems, that require help from a developer in order to be solved.

Since our designer only pushes SCSS files to our repository, we thought that maybe a temporary workaround for this problem would be doing an application wide cache, so he can work on a static version of the whole application and work on the SCSS without worrying about back end compilation process.

I know this is a development process issue, but since we need to find a quick solution and carry on , we thought that maybe this might do the job.

i found this related thread:
[Vaadin 8 - application-wide cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49925756/vaadin-8-application-wide-cache)