# Java library for keeping a synchronised / replicated in-memory copy of remote data

Tags: java

I've had this requirement come up quite a lot and I'm wondering if there is a library that encapsulates this functionality. Essentially it's this:

I have some remote data store (often a database but could be anything) and I'd like to cache the whole thing in memory and periodically check for updates as well as do full refreshes. Ideally the check for updates should only track delta's (so either the remote store provides a stream of updates to the store or the library figures it out by a combination of a 'modified on' and 'archive' fields).

Often I'd use a cache that just looks up the value if it's not in the cache but there are cases where the latency on a cache miss would be unacceptable.

Comment: I think your query is similar to the [Lightweight Java Object cache API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230649/lightweight-java-object-cache-api) question. you can get help from there....

Comment: Thanks Clinton. It is similar but not quite. This is more like an in memory replication. AFAIK, none of those caches handle deltas for example.