# can database caching solutions be used locally in clients and not on the server side?

Tags: java, caching, ehcache, data-synchronization

I'm interested in caching solutions for a client server Java Desktop application both to speed up locally the queries but mostly to limit the network traffic.

Currently each client queries over and over the server each time he has to present the user with a list or manipulate the data and methods like getAllUsers() or findAll() are quite common even inside the same method.

This means the network is quite congested of this type of queries.
I've seen this interesting thread [Lightweight Java Object cache API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230649/lightweight-java-object-cache-api) however I think these libraries work in a way such that the client keeps a cache of queries locally for a certain amount of time before updating its cache with the server.

Most of these Api's however seem to work only in a browser based application where each client requests the server's database for data. 
I'm instead in a client server swing application situation.

Being that my database results have complex relations between them I would need the clients to keep a cache of queries but invalidate their cache as soon as the server database updates because of another client's update, the TTL wouldn't even be necessary because if the server database never changes the cache of clients could very well never expire.

Is there something sort of a database caching and synchronization for desktop applications? can you tell me which caching libraries (Guava, cache4j, whirlyCache, LRUMap, EHCache) also provide this feature or how this type of caching is called?

Comment: Bump... apparently no one to help in this field..