# Java function to return XML.

Tags: java

I have a trivial Java question. I have a function that is supposed to generate a XML file. At the moment I simply have a String return type for the function.

```
public String myXmlFile()
```

I like this approach because it gives me a clean api.

I **do not** like this approach because it puts me in a sticky spot if the xml becomes too large. I know I could create a file and return a handler of the file from the function. However, creating a file gives me the added headache of having to remember to delete this file once I am done with it. And that is not a very easy thing, because the code that uses the XML is not very trivial. It is complex and it is going to change a lot.

So, polling the group to see if there is a easy answer to this?

Comment: Do you get any error while doing this?

Comment: could you please show us the code you have tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sidestep this issue by taking a stream writer as an input parameter, which would allow *the user* (the application calling your API) to decide if the data is small enough to fit into memory, or if the XML is so large it needs to go into a file.  For example:

```
public void myXmlFile(OutputStream output);
```

This keeps your API simple, and allows you to handle both cases.

Comment: Yes. This would be one of the sensible options. However, just being pedantic I guess - in this case is it possible that myXmlFile() function calls some other function (in a different thread) internally and that rises the case that the client of the function is trying to read the outputstream while the helper / internal function is still writing on it?

Comment: Well, yes, in theory, but you'd really have to go out of your way to create that situation ... unless you haven't told us about the sophisticated and very, very clever multithreaded environment in which you would be calling such a function.  That would also, in my far from humble opinion, be serious abuse of the API as you've described it so far.

Comment: I agree. You have a fair point. I guess this is the solution then. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your method might take an OutputStream param then you could write xml by bytes and close when finished.

Answer (score 0):

Just have two methods. The end user of the API can then decide which method to use :

```
public String myXmlFileAsString();
public File myXmlFile();
```

Answer (score 0):

One idea would be to use a caching solution (which could decide whether to store the data in memory or on disk) and to pass around cache keys instead of XML content in your api.

This way you can configure for example the maximum memory you want to use and leave the rest to the library.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230649/lightweight-java-object-cache-api) for a list of possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in XML processing in Java, but why not to investigate whether Xerces has necessary optimizations and just leave optimizations and dealing with files to Xerces. Then you can just return a Xerces XMLString from your method.
http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/javadocs/xni/org/apache/xerces/xni/XMLString.html

Xerces has some optimizations, for example, XMLString is just an XML representation of the substring of string being held in the character buffer of the scanner. But watch out because this pattern (just holding borders without copying a substring into separate string) can sometimes cause a memory leak. (See changes in String in Java7u21.)

Answer (score 0):

Java has extensive support for handling XML built in, why reinvent the wheel?
Create a DOM, use the functionality in the javax.xml.transform package to transform that to a StreamResult, and pipe the Stream to a File.
At its most basic, you'd get something like the following:

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory df = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = df.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = documentBuilder.newDocument();
    Element root = doc.createElement("RootElement");
    doc.appendChild(root);
    Element child = doc.createElement("ChildElement");
    child.setNodeValue("Hello World");
    root.appendChild(child);

    TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
    File f = new File("c:\\temp\\dummy.xml");
    StreamResult resultStream = new StreamResult(f);
    transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), resultStream);
```