# java server side Caching on load balancer enviroment

Tags: java, caching

Have you any idea for implementing caching of data on server side in load balancing environment in java?

Comment: Not really. A cache for what? What should it do, how should it behave? Why does a simple `HashMap` not work? Should it fit into memory? What have you already looked at, what have you tried? Guava, Caffeine, JCache, Memcached, redis, ehcache, cache2k, imcache, jcabi cache? One of those, probably. Did you look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230649/) or [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/575685/)?

Answer (score 0):

You could look at memcached or redis for a shared cache ?